# Unity MVC injecting current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, unity-container

I am using the basic Unity MVC Nuget Bootstrapper.
I would like to Inject the currently logged in user into the services I am defining

```
_container.RegisterType<IDoSomethingService, DoSomethingService>();
```

such that DoSomethingService gets an ICurrentUser object or some form of resolver.

I am trying to avoid having to make calls like

```
DoSomethingService.DoSomething(currentUserUsingService,...);
```

Or in the constructor of all the MVC Controllers also avoiding setting:

```
DoSomethingService.CurrentUSer = User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my projects I use next:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    int? GetId();
}
```

I register next implementation:

```
public class CurrentUserService: ICurrentUserService
{
    public int? GetId()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return null;
        return int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);//When auth - id stored in cookie
    }
}

_container.RegisterType<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
```

And make my services depends on ICurrentUserService (by using ctor parameter) or pass userId into methods of my services in controllers.